Solana Scaffold project failing to push to remote repo
I'm currently working on the bootcamp 2024 and I wanted to push one of the projects I worked on to my github repo. However, when I try pushing, it takes very long to compress objects and produces this error message:
error: RPC failed; HTTP 400 curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 3 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
Writing objects: 100% (221/221), 441.63 MiB | 2.04 MiB/s, done.
Total 221 (delta 75), reused 1 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly

I created the project with the npx create-solana-dapp which creates a big project with lots of files. I want to know if there's an efficient way to push to my repo, maybe some git ignores im missing? I'm not sure why it is failing to begin with

After some time messing around I found that test-ledger was not being properly ignored given the setup of the scaffold. for some reason the test-ledger folder was in my root directory, so its inclusion in the gitignore within the anchor directory wasn't doing anything.
I kept trying to push but it still didn't work so I deleted the .git directory and started the process again and it worked!! Keep an eye out for that test-ledger folder cause the files are massive and if they get tracked by git they'll be a major impediment.
